# Get elements separate from array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, string

What is the best way or elegant way to get all elements whithout spaces and ignore "DOMICILIO" and the next elements for example :
"LOAIZA"
"HERRERA"
"JESUS" (This is my expected output)

In this case I have one string with 2 elements ("LOAIZA\nHERRERA")

["LOAIZA HERRERA", "JESUS", "DOMICILIO", "CALLE1", "CALLE2"]

```
          var dataID = ["LOAIZA HERRERA", "JESUS", "DOMICILIO"]

                    for i in dataID {
                      if i.contains(" "){
                        print(i) // LOAIZA HERRERA
                        let dataSeparate = i.components(separatedBy: " ")
                        print(dataSeparate) // ["LOAIZA", "HERRERA"]
                      }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate the terms by `" "` and `flatMap` into a new array. Then, find the index of "DOMICILIO" if it exists and use the segment of the array up to that point.

```
func findResult(dataID: [String]) -> Array<String> {
    let terms = dataID.flatMap { $0.components(separatedBy: " ")}
    let indexOfDom = terms.firstIndex(of: "DOMICILIO")

    if let indexOfDom = indexOfDom, indexOfDom > 0 {
        return Array(terms[0...(indexOfDom - 1)])
    } else {
        return terms
    }
}
```